# Density of $C^0([0,T]\times M)$ in $L^p([0,T]\times M)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $M$ be a compact $C^2$ hypersurface embedded in $\mathbb{R}^n$ of dimension $n-1$. Is the space $C^0([0,T]\times M)$ dense in $L^p([0,T]\times M)$?

How do I prove this or what theorem can I use?

Comment: You can use patches to cover $M$ and for each patch use local coordinates of $n-1$ dimension. Then, using mollifier to get smooth approximation of any $L^p$ function. This could be found in Necas or Adams, (not very sure).

Comment: Just a guess: Can't you use the fact, that for a $X$ a locally compact Hausdorff space $C(X)$ is dense in $L^{p}(X)$? But, of course, I do not know, if your $[0,T]\times M$ is locally compact Hausdorff...

Comment: @HuiZhang But my $M$ is only $C^2$ so smooth $C^\infty$ functions don't make sense..

Comment: @Alex Yeah that is what I am hoping for but no idea about those terms.

Comment: @aca888 $C^\infty$ is w.r.t. the patch coordinate in $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}.$ Afterwards, $C^2$ embedding in $\mathbb{R}^n$ gives $C^2$ function w.r.t. the coordinate in $\mathbb{R}^n.$